# Passing form variable to a partial template - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an edit page that uses a semantic_form_for tag

```
<%= semantic_form_for @photog do |f| %>
```

The form is getting quite long and I would like to break it up into sections so that the view is more readable.

I am trying to create partials within the edit.html.erb template such as

```
  <%= render 'favorite_things', locals: {f: f} %>
```

This code breaks saying 
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#:0x007ff5a110abf0>

I need to understand how to pass the f object so that the partial can read it and things like f.input work

```
 <!-- favorite things partial -->
 <div class='edit_photog_header'>A List Of Your Favorites</div>
 <%= f.input :fav_lens, :label => "Lens" %>
 <%= f.input :fav_camera, :label => "Camera" %>
 [and so on]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`locals` is for when you're using `render partial`.

```
<%= render partial: path_to_partial, locals: locals_hash %>
```

If you're just using `render`, you should do this:

```
<%= render path_to_view, locals_hash %>
```

Which in your case would be:

```
<%= render 'favorite_things', f: f %>
```